# Returning value of an <input> using a button

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have seen a couple of similar questions, but everything I've attempted so far has failed and I hope someone can make it clearer what noob-error I'm having here.
Thing is I have a rather large automatically generated number of tables and now I need a simple JQuery to get the hidden uniqe ID of each row and use them as an input for an Ajax script. And here I'm frustrated because I am not even able to get that stupid number...
Well, right now the row contains the ID and a button to get it like this:

```
<div class="pull-right">
     <input type="hidden" class="thisSeriesID" th:value="${appointment.seriesID}">
     <button class="btn btn-default entryChecker"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
</div>
```

Now I'm currently using this JQuery to get the ID and test whether it worked or not. It is just the latest of many attempts, but just as useless:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".entryChecker").click(function(){
            var x = $(this).prev().val();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.toString();
            });
        }
        );
</script>
```

My aim is of course that if I push any of the buttons, I get the respective ID in this line:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

But as you people who are more clever than me might have guessed: Nothing happens.
Can anyone give me a hint where I messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>


     $( document ).ready(function() {
         $(".entryChecker").click(function(){
            var myvalue = $(this).prev('.thisSeriesID').val();
            console.log(myvalue);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myvalue;
            });
                 });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pull-right">
     <input type="hidden" class="thisSeriesID"  value="5" />
     <button class="btn btn-default entryChecker"> Check<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
</div>
    <div id="demo"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Even though it was one of my previous attempts and now that I tested it again, it still doesn't work.

Comment: please remove th: infront of your value on hiden field

Comment: And here I thought th:value is a valid thymeleaf statement I need to read my Java class that contains the table information. Thing is, if I erase it, again nothing changes. It still doesn't work.
I wonder whether it could be an error because the ID is an integer...

Comment: Okay wow. I've made some slight modifications to your solution (I've basically only stuck to my "$(function()"-beginning) and now it suddenly works, even with non-static values.
I'm currently a little stumped due to it being really not that different to my previous solution. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First `th:value is not any attribute, use value instead of it.

you can use data-* property to get the unique id

```
  <div class="pull-right">
     <button class="btn btn-default entryChecker" data-uniqueid ="${appointment.seriesID}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".entryChecker").click(function(){
            var x = $(this).data('uniqueid');
            $("#demo").html(x);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using thymeleaf, so I think I need th:value to get my data. Well, I'm going to try your version, but I somehow doubt the button will know what an appointment is when I use it like this.

Comment: data-* attr contains the uniqueid when you click it will get it. demo - https://jsbin.com/yurayozuxi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's not what I mean. ;) I have no doubts that your version works for a static website, but I get my data from an external database and am trying to figure out a solution that works with thymeleaf.

Comment: can you elaborate it like getting data from database ? It will work whether you have static table or dynamic generated table.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `th:value` as an input attribute, then you need use `attr('th:value')` to get its value. Here is js:

```
$(function(){
                $(".entryChecker").click(function(){
                  var hidden= $(this).prev("input[type='hidden']");
                  var val = hidden.attr('th:value');
                  $("#demo").html(val);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide the final html?

Comment: 500 lines of code? I don't think that's necessary.
It is just a hunch, but... do you think it is possible that the value is null because the data given to me by the Java program reading the database returns an Integer?

Comment: This code can return null, only if  your `${appointment.seriesID}` is null.

Comment: Well, so much for that. Now that it works with Mujeebu Rahman's solution, I can safely say that the error isn't caused by the value.